# Gradle: error: package de.congrace.exp4j does not exist

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm getting the error :

```
Gradle: error: package de.congrace.exp4j does not exist
```

I added the exp4j.jar file into the project under :
TestProject - idea - libraries , is that correct or where do I have to add it normally?

I also tried in the build.gradle file to add

```
dependencies {
compile ('libs/exp4j.jar')
}
```

but it didnt work,
there is also a second gradle file in Test-src-build.gradle which looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

I have no idea what to do... can anybody help plz?
edit: I also added the file exp4j.jar manually in the explorer ... Test/build/libs folder and it still didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

See the [Gradle doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):

1) You could write

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/exp4j-0.3.10.jar')
}
```

or 2) define the libs directory as repository

```
repositories {
    flatDir dirs:'libs'
}
```

and then reference it with

```
dependencies {
    compile 'de.congrace:exp4j:0.3.10'
}
```

or 3) you do not place it in the libs directory and declare it as a standard dependency from Maven central:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'de.congrace:exp4j:0.3.10'
}
```

Do not mix IDEA settings with Gradle settings. If you add the library to IDEA compile path, Gradle will not know about this setting. If you add the library to Gradle and execute a Gradle build in IDEA then it will work.

**Update**: all 3 variants are tested and are working!

Comment: so where exactly do I have to put my .jar file? there is no libs directory shown in the Project explorer ... just a libraries under idea somewhere... I dont know where to put the file :( EDIT: and when I put dependencies {
    compile files('libs/exp4j.jar')
} in the build.gradle I get another error message:Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'TestProject'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [libs/exp4j.jar] on root project 'TestProject'.

Comment: Did you try 3)? I saw you are using Android Tools - which Tools versionand which Android version? How did you update the Intellij project? Why is in your build.gradle no exp4j dependency?